# Making a linear potentiometer in an html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to put an horizontal scrollbar to make a kind of linear potentiometer in a web page.
I want the user to move a cursor from left to right and set a position for setting a value.

How can i do this ?

Thanks

Comment: `<input type="range">` should do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Input[type=range]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range) is what you are looking for:

```html
<input type="range" min="-10" max="10" step="0.1" onchange="console.log(this.value)">
```